# does std::ofstream close properly upon segfault?

Tags: c++, logging, segmentation-fault, std

Does std::ofstream closes properly and flushes the buffer when my process segfault? I am suspecting that the log messages immediately prior to the segfault are missing and it is a pain to debug a long running c++ server without those log messages :( Does anyone know what is the proper way to log to file?

Comment: Flush your logging streams after every write!

Comment: This would require the standard library to have interrupt handlers to catch the segfault. I don't think the standard library has any interrupt handlers.

Comment: If you add timestamps to your logs you might get a better sense of whether logs are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segfaults generally result from undefined behavior in the program; in those cases there's no guarantee of what will happen.  Practically speaking, without a handler function, segfaults generally cause a program to halt immediately, so there's no chance for the ofstream to flush itself.

You can work around this by always ending your logging code by writing std::endl to the stream.  This has the side effect of flushing the stream.

Comment: would it be possible to add a signal handler `signal(SIGSEGV, handleSignal);` and flush the logs in handleSignal?

Comment: Its undefined behavior to call standard library functions from a signal handler, so it might work, or it might not.